# GLIBCXX_3.4.26 not found on centos

Tags: libstdc++

I am facing this issue on centos:-

/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found

Gcc version i have is :- gcc version 7.2.0 (GCC)

How can i install GLIBCXX_3.4.26 on centos 7.8?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your application using the system compiler or GCC from Developer Toolset. Developer Toolset uses a hybrid linkage model which avoids these errors. This functionality is likely missing from your custom build of GCC.